# Complex number troubles with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm attempting to translate some matlab code again and I've run into another pickle. The code itself is very simple, it's just a demonstration of a 4 node twiddle factor. Here is my attempt:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 


x = zeros(4)
x[-1+1] = 0
x[0+1] = 1
x[1+1] = 1
x[2+1] = 0

z = 0 - 1j
W4 = exp(z*2*pi/4)
W0 = W4 ** 0
W1 = W4 ** 1
W2 = W4 ** 2
W3 = W4 ** 3


X = zeros(4)
X[-1+1] = (x[-1+1] + x[1+1]*W0) + W0*(x[0+1] + x[2+1]*W0)
X[0+1] = (x[-1+1] + x[1+1]*W2) + W1*(x[0+1] + x[2+1]*W2)
X[1+1] = (x[-1+1] + x[1+1]*W0) + W2*(x[0+1] + x[2+1]*W0)
X[2+1] = (x[-1+1] + x[1+1]*W2) + W3*(x[0+1] + x[2+1]*W2)


fx = fft.fft(x) 

plt.plot(X)
plt.plot(fx, 'ro')
plt.title("Results 4-point hand programmed FFT (blue) and the PYTHON routine (red o)")
plt.show()
```

Here are the output images. The first one is run with (almost) identical matlab code, the second one is the image from the python code above.
[image: matlab output]

[image: py output]
For lines 24 to 27 it gives me the error "ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part". Now I'm not used to working with complex numbers in python. I tried adding a complex component to all the variables, but it gave me a graph that's way off from the matlab one. Thoughts? If you would like me to post the matlab code as well, let me know.

Comment: Are lines 24-27 the lines W4 ** x? If so, it seems like ** is not defined for complex numbers, so it is casting W to a real and then doing the power.

Comment: No it's just simple multiplication for those lines, the exponentitation is only in lines 17-20

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you specify the array `x` and `X` you need to make sure it is of complex data type, i.e:

```
x = zeros((4),dtype=complex)
```

EDIT:

To fix the plot you need to plot both real and imaginary parts:

```
plt.plot(X.real,X.imag)
plt.plot(fx.real,fx.imag, 'ro')
```

This gives me:

[image]

....which looks like your Matlab graph.